# Laravel 5.3 - Prevent duplicate notifications for notifiable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a notifiable `User`, `user 1` and `user 2` are used in this example.

If `user 2` upvotes `user 1` question, `user 1` receives an email and a `toArray` notification inserted into the database, which looks like this:

```
public function toArray($notifiable){
    return [
        'upvoter_username' => $this->event->upvoter->username,
        'question_id' => $this->event->question->id,
        'question_title' => $this->event->question->title,
    ];
}
```

The issue I am facing is when `user 2` goes back and `downvotes` the same question (no issue), and then re-upvotes the question again (issue here).

In short, `user 1` receives the same email again and the notification gets inserted into the database again; `user 1` should only be notified once, the first time.

How can I ensure  that the notification will ***not*** notify the notifiable `user 1` twice for the same upvote by `user 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store the notifications in a separate table, with two fields : question_id, upvoter_id. If a row already exists for the `user 2` and the question_id, dont send the email, otherwise add row and send the mail.